# Getting *started* with Virtualisation - at a high level

Tags: networking, virtualization, hypervisor

I'm a student on an industrial placement within the university's IT department and my boss wants me to head up a project to virtualise our lab environment.

And while I've run a few VMs at home or school I've never set up a system of this sort so need some tips on where to look for information.

The labs are used by the Forensics and Security degree students but are available for any student (when such classes aren't using them) so I'm hoping that it's possible to set up the client machines such that when turning the computer on they're presented with a text (or gui) menu of VM's to load. There should be no access to options, or changes without a password.

Each VM would have its own passwords/usernames assigned by a domain server.

One of the VM's is for the Ethical Hacker class so each time a Kali linux VM instance goes live it would need to automatically create a virtual switch and a second VM as a vulnerable machine for them to practice hacking/counter hacking (in an ideal world I'd like that visible on a second screen so they can also practice securing/patching faults - don't know how possible that is on a single machine).

The computers we have at the moment are overkill for thin clients so if at all possible it would be handy if they could share resources.

Finally the VMs should be accessible externally.

Question 1 - what system(s) can get me the closest to what I want? 
Question 2 - where best to learn this sort of thing?
Question 3 - I had a thought to create a simulacrum of the lab in mini by getting a spare server, and a space PC and creating a test version - I should be able to do this with a server/switch/PC yes?

I've been given the task today - and have till the beginning of term (end of September) hence my wanting at least some direction before I go off into the wild.

Comment: Windows10 Enterprise+HyperV combination would be best. I learn about virtualization from **Virtualization Essentials** book. PDF [link](http://www.tu-varna.bg/tu-varnaknt/images/tutorials/vt/ve.pdf).

Comment: Thanks GreenMatt for the timely edit for typos - I was typing at silly o'clock in the morning. 

Biswa I'm trying to avoid running a VM in an OS and want to go bare metal at the client side - so we can in the future recommission the PCs there for other labs and replace them with very light weight thin-client units. If possible (there are licensing issues I'm exploring with the vendors)

Comment: HyperV is type-1 hypervisor or bare-metal hypervisors. It is not like Type-2 which are VirtualBox or VMWare.

Comment: I mean that running the hypervisor with the management software on the same machine is the opposite of what I'm after.

I need the computer to boot to a menu (whether GUI or text) of VM's stored on a separate software and the general user should only be able to choose which VM to run, rather than have any administrative control over the hardware

Comment: Are you searching for like this [Lime Technology unRAID Server](https://lime-technology.com/)? Se this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuJYMCbIbPk).